# Maximum length in bits of the product n=pq

Tags: rsa, public-key

If p and q are two 1024-bit prime numbers, would the maximum length in bits of product $n=pq$ be ${1024}^2$ or $2^{1024}$?

I think it is ${1048576}={1024}^2$?

Also, would the least significant bit of $n$ be a $0$ or a $1$? I am assuming it would be $0$? Any explanation of what determines significance would be great

Comment: You are assuming a least significant bit of zero for two (large) prime numbers? Which one of them is even?

Answer (score 8):

If $p$ and $q$ are 1024-bit primes, then by definition of the bit size of an integer (at least, a prime in a cryptographic context with glimpses of RSA), $2^{1023}\le p<2^{1024}$ and $2^{1023}\le q<2^{1024}$. Thus their product $n=pq$ verifies $2^{2046}\le n<2^{2048}$, and $n$ is a 2047-bit or 2048-bit integer. We show by exhibition that both cases are possible, with $p=q=2^{1023}+1155$ for the first case, and $p=q=2^{1024}-105$ for the second.

Hence the *maximum* length in bits of the product $n=pq$ is $2048=2\cdot1024$.

This generalizes to: for *odd* primes $p$ and $q$, the *maximum* length in bits of the product $n=pq$ is the sum of the bit length of primes $p$ and $q$; proof that this bound is tight can be obtained from the observation that $\forall k>1,\exists p\text{ prime with }2^{k-1/2}<p<2^k$, which itself follows from stronger versions of [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Since $p$ and $q$ are large primes, they are odd, hence $pq$ is odd, hence the least significant bit of $n=pq$ is 1.

Addition: in common RSA key generation standards [FIPS 186-4 appendix B.3](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=59) and ancestor ANSI X9.31-1998, it is chosen primes $p$ and $q$ with $2^{k-1/2}<p<2^k$ and $2^{k-1/2}<q<2^k$, which insures that $pq$ is *exactly* $2k$ bits.

Comment: As we are clearly talking about RSA here, it would be *nice* to explain how $n$ is set to be exactly the key size during key pair generation - obviously that does not lead from the $pq$ calculation in itself.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Cannot vote up more though :)

Answer (score 4):

Any integer $n$ can be represented in binary form in $\left \lfloor{log_2{n}}\right \rfloor + 1$ bits.

Now coming to your problem where $n = pq$. Number of bits to represent $n$ is $\left \lfloor{log_2{n}}\right \rfloor + 1 =  \left \lfloor{log_2{pq}}\right \rfloor + 1 = \left \lfloor{log_2{p}+log_2{q}}\right \rfloor + 1$.

By the properties of the floor function,
$\left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor {y} \right \rfloor \le \left \lfloor {x+y} \right \rfloor \le \left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor
+ \left \lfloor {y} \right \rfloor + 1$, and $\left \lfloor {log_2p} \right \rfloor = 1023$ and $\left \lfloor {log_2q} \right \rfloor = 1023$, we have

$1023+1023+1 \le \text{bits for representing n} \le 1023+1023+1+1$. Thus, simplifying to $2047 \le \text{bits for representing n}\le 2048$.

**Added**:
Since primes are odd, and multiplication of odds is odd, $LSB(n) = 1$. (assuming neither of them is 2).

Comment: Partial answer at best, there were two related questions.

Comment: @owlstead updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the total number of bits after multiplication will be 2*1024.
In binary form take for eg. 3 (2 bits = 11) * 3 (2 bits = 11) = 9 (4 bits = 1001 in binary)

Comment: Partial answer at best, there were two related questions.

Comment: The assertion _the total number of bits after multiplication will be 2*1024_ is incorrect; counterexample: $p=q=2^{1023}+1155$.

Comment: so there will not be a maximum of 2048 bits?

Comment: @fgrieu How did you find such $p, q$?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: `NextPrime[2^1023]-2^1023` is `1555` according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime[2^1023]-2^1023)

Comment: @cryptoclk: the _maximum_ size indeed is 2048 bits; the answer I commented reaches the correct numeric answer to the question, but puts that in a formally incorrect statement (notice _total_ is not the same as _maximum_).